# Вызов методов MainActivity из других классов

Tags: java, android

Есть `MainActivity`, в нём есть 2 метода.
Первый сохраняет строку:

```
public void saveInfo(String lvl){
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
    editor.putString("lvl", lvl);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Второй выгружает строку:

```
public String getInfo(){
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lvl = sPref.getString("lvl", "");
    return lvl;
}
```

Внутри `MainActivity` всё работает отлично, но как только я пытаюсь вызвать эти методы из другого класса, приложение крашится.

Что я делаю не так?

Как я вызываю метод из другого класса:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.saveInfo("2");
```

Я хочу сохранять данные в `SharedPreferences` из других классов, но не могу.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Жизненным циклом активности должна управлять операционная система. Активность нельзя инстанцировать с помощью оператора `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Управлять `Activity` и фрагментами должна операционная система. Создавать `Activity` нужно средствами SDK, к примеру, с помощью [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#StartActivity).

> Я хочу сохранять данные в `SharedPreferences` из других классов, но не могу.

Для использования `SharedPreferences` вам нужен `Context`.

Можно сделать методы `static`:

```
public static void saveInfo(Context ctx, String lvl){
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
    editor.putString("lvl", lvl);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Второй выгружает строку:

```
public static String getInfo(Context ctx){
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lvl = sPref.getString("lvl", "");
    return lvl;
}
```

И вызывать тогда так:

```
MainActivity.saveInfo(yourContext, "2");
```

Comment: методы общего доступа  в активити не очень как то решение ...

Comment: @pavlofff само собой. Я просто хотел показать, как переписать код с минимум затрат.

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант - создайте статическую переменную на объект приложения:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static App _app;
    public static App getApp()
    {
        return _app;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       _app = this;
    }

    public void saveInfo(String lvl){
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
        editor.putString("lvl", lvl);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getInfo(){
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String lvl = sPref.getString("lvl", "");
        return lvl;
    }
}
```

Далее можно вызывать в коде:

```
App.getApp().getInfo()
```